# How to use ls in nslookup on HP-UX?

Tags: nslookup

I don't understand how to use the `ls` option in `nslookup` on HP-UX. It failed both interactively:

```
> ls
Using /etc/hosts on:  hpux

looking up FILES
Trying DNS
Name:    ls.

> set ls
*** Invalid option: ls
>
```

And non-interactively:

```
nslookup  -query=PTR 10.3.0.2 10.3.0.2 ls
```

What's the right way to use it?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The Windows flavour of `nslookup` has a `ls` subcommand. However, that's not unix.

Comment: @thrig yes it is. Just that most Linux based versions of `nslookup` no longer bother to implement it.

Comment: Don't use (deprecated) nslookup(1), use dig(1)

Comment: Yes i use dig usually but for complete unix culture even nslookup mean to be know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken straight from [HPUX documentation for `nslookup`](http://www.admin-sys.com/nslookup-hpux)

> **ls [option] domain** List the information available for domain [...]. The default output contains host names and their Internet addresses.

The `ls` subcommand will work only if you are connecting to an authoritative server *and* you have permission to request a zone transfer.

```
nslookup - 10.1.1.1    # The authoritative server for zone contoso.com
> ls contoso.com
```